# How to Get Lilypond Music Engraver to Render File in SVG Format

Tags: lilypond, engraving

I am looking to get Lilypond to output my scores in SVG format. I'm working on the Windows 10 platform. So far I have only been able to get png outputs using the following command in the command line:

lilypond -fpng Name_of_File.ly

I can not figure out what command or string of commands will give an svg output but I suspect it will be similar to the above png output command. I have played with the dbackend command but have not been able to even get that to work.  In case it is of any help, the following link contains some disjointed and incomplete explanations of getting svg outputs:

http://lilypond.org/doc/v2.18/Documentation/usage/command_002dline-usage.en.html#advanced-command-line-options-for-lilypond

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use this just like the first example from the page you linked:

```
lilypond -dbackend=svg filename.ly
```

Comment: Great thank you. You should write the documentation for Lilypond.